# Yearly Reputation is off by 101

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

My current reputation is 2347. But when I look at the reputation for the year it is 2246. I only joined in 2011, so can't figure out why that would be?

Just curious.

Comment: Maybe Cruella De Vil stole the 101rep?! :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't forget you get +100 for having +200 across the network.

Beyond that, https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: But why then is the difference 2347-2246=101, and not 100?

Comment: @Werner: Probably because you start out with one "free" point.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks... I should have noticed something to that effect about Jeff's never-changing baseline reputation of **101**.

Comment: @werner nobody starts out as a *zero*.

Comment: @Jeff: Excuse my sarcasm, but that was both *accurate* and *deep*.